# Making WSDL parameters optional

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm trying to work with the Microsoft Exchange EWS protocol, for which Microsoft provide a WSDL file. I'm generate a JAX-WS client library from this using `wsimport`.

Unfortunately, Microsoft's WSDL file is faulty. One of the things it is getting wrong (apparently) is that all SOAP request parameters are defined as mandatory --- except they're not, they're optional, and in some situations I have to be able to not supply them.

Excerpt from the WSDL file:

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetUserAvailability">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/GetUserAvailability" />
    <wsdl:input>
        <soap:header message="tns:GetUserAvailabilitySoapIn" part="Impersonation" use="literal"/>
        <soap:header message="tns:GetUserAvailabilitySoapIn" part="TimeZoneContext" use="literal"/>
        <soap:header message="tns:GetUserAvailabilitySoapIn" part="RequestVersion" use="literal"/>
        <soap:body parts="GetUserAvailabilityRequest" use="literal" />
        <soap:header message="tns:GetUserAvailabilitySoapIn" part="RequestVersion" use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
        ...skipped...
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>

<wsdl:message name="GetUserAvailabilitySoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="GetUserAvailabilityRequest" element="tns:GetUserAvailabilityRequest" />
    <wsdl:part name="Impersonation" element="t:ExchangeImpersonation"/>
    <wsdl:part name="TimeZoneContext" element="t:TimeZoneContext" />
    <wsdl:part name="RequestVersion" element="t:RequestServerVersion"/>
</wsdl:message>

<xs:element name="ExchangeImpersonation" type="t:ExchangeImpersonationType"/>
```

If I call this with, say, `service.getUserAvailability(request, null, null, version)`, then I get an `<ExchangeImpersonation xsl:nil="true"/>` element in the header, and the Exchange server complains about having an extraneous element.

So, I want to edit the WSDL file to make these parameters properly optional. I've tried adding various combinations of `wsdl:required=false` and `minOccurs=0` to various places according to the docs, but `wsimport` appears to be ignoring them completely --- the resulting code is unchanged.

How do I do this?

Comment: How about adding nillable="true" to ur schema

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not Microsoft, which means I'm unable to modify the schema with which Exchange validates incoming requests.